# Using jquery/javascript to check if pdf is embedded or send to download

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, iframe

I'm working on some old legacy ASP code where users can upload/attach multiple files. The files are stored in a database and upon request (clicking a link to displayattachment.asp?attachmentGuid=....) the attachment should be shown/downloaded. Like on [Attempting to view pdf file though iframe using jQuery modal popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780089/attempting-to-view-pdf-file-though-iframe-using-jquery-modal-popup) the displayattachment.asp page set header

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="somefile.ext"
```

On the client side I have a jquery dialog with an iframe:

```
function DisplayAttachmentWindow(sAttachmentGuid) {
    $("#attachmentDiv").dialog({
            close: function () {
                $("#attachmentDiv").empty();
            },
            modal: true,
            height: 800,
            width: 1400,
            open: function () {
                $(this).html('<iframe src="displayattachment.asp?AttachmentGuid=' + sAttachmentGuid + '" style="width:100%; height:100%;" id="attachmentIframe"></iframe>');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

and then:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow: hidden;" id="attachmentDiv" title=""></div>
```

What I want to do is the following:
If the file (eg. picture or pdf) is displayed in the dialog everything is fine.
If the file is to be downloaded (like my IE 10 does for pdf's and all browsers do for word/excel files), the dialog should close again imidiately or maybe not even be displayed at all (I think that is impossible).

I have tried an onLoad handler on the iframe, but that is not fired in IE. I have also tried accessing `$("#attachmentIframe").contents()` manually (using console) to see if the file was embedded, but that gives me an error in firefox

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'
```

Does anyone know any way to check if the file was displayed by the browser (or plugin) or simply downloaded?